# Entity Framework connection string error

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity

I have this connectionstring in app.config

```
 <appSettings>
 <add key="CBREEntities"  value="metadata=res://*/CBRE.csdl|res://*/CBRE.ssdl|res://*/CBRE.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=aqp4ewzly1-bp_toolkit_prd_0006-20160923T050628Z;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" />
 <add key="elmah-sqlserver" value="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=aqp4ewzly1-bp_toolkit_prd_0006-20160923T050628Z;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
 </appSettings>
```

and this in web.config.cshtml

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="CBREEntities" connectionString="@Model["CBREEntities"]" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   <add name="elmah-sqlserver" connectionString="@Model["elmah-sqlserver"]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Entity framework generates this connection string in web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CBREEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CBRE.csdl|res://*/CBRE.ssdl|res://*/CBRE.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=aqp4ewzly1-bp_toolkit_prd_0006-20160923T050628Z;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="elmah-sqlserver" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=aqp4ewzly1-bp_toolkit_prd_0006-20160923T050628Z;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and after running app I have this error

It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING

already tested replacing ' with " and replacing entityclient to sqlclient

Answer (score 0):

Try delete your connectionStrings in your web.config.cshtml

I'd never put connectionstring in web.config.cshtml and all my applications woks fine.

I hope help!